# Can't disarm missile in "Dark Water" mission in MW II

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii

As it seems I've encountered a game-breaking bug in MW II in a single player mission on PC.

In Dark Water you're supposed to find and disarm a missile. I've found it and got to the controls in order to interact with them.

All side missions leading there are completed and I made sure every enemy is dead. Also I started over from last checkpint and the whole mission and still no dice.

I had to scale down the images (a lot) to meet the 2 MB limit, but they should still do.

Mission progress:

[image]

Found them, but I'm not able to interact with them:

[image]

---

I'm guessing there's something prior to finding the case that got me stuck, because on YouTube the NPC follow you into the room. For me, they don't. Since I cleared every single room on that ship, what can I have missed? Even twice since restarting the mission did not help...

YouTube screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and have figured out the problem. The character “Graves” must’ve gotten stuck in the crates or killed during the mission. If he gets stuck, Ghost will sit outside the Bridge (where the bomb controls are) and wait indefinitely. Restart the mission and make sure both Graves & Ghost are with you, they should follow you automatically and you shouldn’t have to protect them.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [IGN.com walkthrough](https://www.ign.com/wikis/call-of-duty-mw2/Dark_Water) you "simply" need to find and neutralise all enemies and once this is done you can continue with the bomb interaction.

It says in the walkthrough that you should move **with** your team, which I can't read if you have done or if you moved ahead of your team and might have missed a trigger point or interaction with your team.

If nothing helps completely restarting this stage (not from a mid-level autosave) should bypass this block.

So far I have read about other bugs stopping game progress but have not read about the one you described.
Make as well sure to keep your game up to date as currently Activision keeps updating the game a lot to fix post-launch bugs.

Comment: Not following the team would have stopped me way before. There is a point where you need them to knock on the door with an explosive "key". And the screenshot with the mission progress shows I have killed them all and advanced to the bomb stage. Also I've already restarted from last checkpoint and the mission all over (as mentioned in my question). Since I'm doing this on veteran repeating the mission again and again is kinda hard. The weather and lighting outside on the deck are a real pain.

Comment: I understand your point and feel your pain on this difficulty setting! Just today I did. have to download another update and hope that this glitch soon is fixed. I didn’t come across it yet myself, but I did not play on that difficulty and it might be triggered only on this Setting.